# Google Places API - How to limit the search limit to just one city

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I wont to limit the search limit to just one city (e.g "New York")
and I need help with componentRestrictions options.
Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {
        var options = {
            types: ['address'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: "us", locality: "new york"}
        };
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict it by adding NY_ Before your input example if you want to search Port Washington then your input will be NY_port_washington

[Example Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=APIKEY&input=NY_port_washington&components=country:us)